# How create a frame for our video?

Tags: iframe, video, video-streaming

I have a video which I want users to see in my webpage. I have uploaded that video on youtube also.

My current coding is

```
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ilbR0MiH6Ho"></iframe>
```

But this shows the video in the style(with same loaders, buttons, interface, etc..) it is being shown at youtube...

But I want it to be shown in other style like it is shown in some other sites like http://www.apple.com/your-verse/#video-your-verse It has a different style of viewing videos!!

That way, I also want to create my own frame to view my video(with a play button of my designing, my loading bar, my interface, etc..)

Can anyone out there help me with that?? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

if you need your own 'player' or 'skin', you will have to use the available players like "JWPlayer" or "flowplayer" or create your own. Then you will have to host your videos elsewhere, where a streaming link has to be obtained.

Its not easy unless you have the technical skills required to create your own video player. But you can use the existing opensource players like I mentioned before.